# Android - LIBGDX FileHandle doesn't write to local file

Tags: android, libgdx, save, filehandle

In my game, there is a `highscore` that is supposed to be saved.

```
private void saveHighscore()
{
    FileHandle file = Gdx.files.local("asdwdasfwad/asdawwafs.txt");
    String highscoreString = Integer.toString(this.highscore);
    file.writeString(highscoreString, false);
    Gdx.app.log("saving", "saving");
}

private int loadHighscore()
{
    FileHandle file = Gdx.files.local("asdwdasfwad/asdawwafs.txt");
    String highscoreString = file.readString();
    int highscore = Integer.parseInt(highscoreString);
    Gdx.app.log("loading", "loading");
    return highscore;
}
```

When I run this on my phone, `"saving"` is logged into the console without any errors, even though the path I have specified (asdwdasfwad/asdawwafs.txt) doesn't even exist. Even if I use an existent path, no file is created.

Comment: So then it runs fine and shows expectated behaviour on desktop?

Comment: I haven't tested it on desktop because I didn't set up the LIBGDX project to support desktop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a direct answer to your problem, but since you just want to save a highscore:

You can just use *Preferences* for this. Its an class provided by libGDX that allows you to easily save small data.

For further information visit the official documentation page: 
[Click here](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Preferences)